# Eclipse CDT static library at constant location?

Tags: c, static, linker, embedded, bootloader

ARM cortex embedded application.

I have a bootloader that is 40KB, mostly crypto for signature of flash.

I have a 500KB flash.

The chip’s sectors are 128KB. And the protection scheme means the first sector must contain the bootloader. Meaning my 40KB bootloader will occupy all 128KB of this sector.

I would like to retake some of this wasted space by including my application crypto libraries.

```
SECTOR0
[64KB bootloader reserved]
[64KB statics]

SECTORn
[application references static]
…
```

1. Can I put a static crypto library at a specific location like this with CDT/GCC and with the managed builder?
2. I am considering this part of the “bootloader code” so I am assuming that I will at least need to modify the .ld file to create a new region?
3. The application will need to know the results from this linking, but to not include the code and place in memory itself - is this still a static link? There are maybe only three or four functions I want to access from application in the library.

*(There are no MPU issues to deal with, I am confident I can jump to the static code area and back even though it’s in the first sector. This static area is intended to be execute only. I am confident only my application software can be installed and executed in the flash region)*